# How to solve $\ddot{x} + \epsilon \dot{x} +\sin x = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have tried as follows

$$\ddot{x} + \epsilon \dot{x} +\sin x = 0$$
$$\therefore  \frac{d}{dt}[(\dot{x})^2e^{2\epsilon t}] = 2\frac{d}{dt}{(\cos x)}e^{2\epsilon t}$$
$$\therefore \frac{d}{dt}\bigg\{\big[(\dot{x})^2 - 2\cos x\big]e^{2\epsilon t}\bigg\} = -4 e^{2\epsilon t} \cos x $$

The last step was a leap of faith...
I can integrate both sides, but I can not see that getting me further.

The exact solution is:

$$x(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{\epsilon^2}{4}}} e^{\frac{-\epsilon t}{2}}\sin(t\sqrt{1-\frac{\epsilon^2}{4}})$$

I would like to get to it.

EDIT :

I am convinced the first inferences are correct.
$$\ddot{x} + \epsilon \dot{x} +\sin x = 0$$
$$2\ddot{x}\dot{x} + 2\epsilon (\dot{x})^2 +2\dot{x}\sin x = 0$$
$$2\ddot{x}\dot{x}e^{2\epsilon t} + 2\epsilon (\dot{x})^2e^{2\epsilon t}+2\dot{x}e^{2\epsilon t}\sin x = 0$$

$$\frac{d}{dt}\{(\dot{x})^2\}e^{2\epsilon t} + (\dot{x})^2\frac{d}{dt}\{e^{2\epsilon t}\}+2\dot{x}e^{2\epsilon t}\sin x = 0$$

$$\therefore  \frac{d}{dt}[(\dot{x})^2e^{2\epsilon t}] = 2\frac{d}{dt}{(\cos x)}e^{2\epsilon t}$$
What part of the above is incorrect?

$$\frac{d}{dt}\{(\dot{x})^2\} = \frac{d}{d\dot{x}}\{\dot{x}^2\}\frac{d \dot{x}}{dt}$$

and using the chain rule on the $\sin x$ term we get the right hand side. A gentleman mentioned elliptic integrals in the comments, I have had a look on wikipedia and I am not entirely sure how to apply.

Comment: Your first inference is invalid because you've conflated differentiating the cosine with respect to $x$ on the LHS with taking a time derivative on the RHS.

Comment: I guess this is related with the exact period of a pendulum with a dissipative force that depends on the speed. Do you know the solution for $\varepsilon=0$, related with the inversion of an elliptic integral?

Comment: I do not know what an elliptic integral is, sorry.

Comment: I am sure the first inference is good.

Comment: Then I guess you stand no chance of finding the explicit solution of such differential equation. What is the purpose of solving it / the original problem?

Comment: I am learning perturbation expansions and this is one of the examples of a problem where the method of single time scales fails.

Comment: If its a perturbation, shouldnt you expand it in an infinite sum?

Comment: I did, the second term is of the form $t \sin t$ (could be wrong) which tends to infinite. I was hoping to try and get an exact solution. Is there a way to progress to obtain $x(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{\epsilon^2}{4}}} e^{\frac{-\epsilon t}{2}}\sin(t\sqrt{1-\frac{\epsilon^2}{4}})$

Comment: You do not even get an symbolic solution for the unperturbed equation, as you can not solve $\dot x^2+4\sin^2(x/2)=C$ further. Which means especially that $x(t)=\sin(t)$ is not a solution of it.